# User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a User Profile Service Application in central admin. The service says it is starting but when you click on the link it returns the following:

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID:
>   5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8

Looking in the log file I see the following corresponding to the Correlation ID.

```
User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   g22d    High        UserProfileApplication.DumpSynchronizationStatusToFile: Unexpected exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager.IsSynchronizationRunning(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.DumpSynchronizationStatusToFile().   5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   et8j    High        UserProfileServiceUserStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)    5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   et8j    High        UserProfileServiceAudienceStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)    5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   et8j    High        UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.IsProfileSynchronizationRunning()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart.RenderSectionContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.Render(HtmlTextWriter ... 5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollectio...  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...n children)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the managed account which you have associated. Just check the application pool in IIS if it is started

Answer (score 7):

Execute IISReset on the server running user profile service application (USPA) and restart USPA service.

Comment: worked for me. For good measure restarts the SharePoint timer job as well.

Answer (score 3):

This issue happens mostly on the Farm installation. Everyone will say to recreate the UPS, restart the server and then it should work fine. But if you have used the Custom properties and created a managed property in Search then its very difficult to recreate it and then to create it again. The better solution so far i have researched is the following

1. Stop the User Profile Synchronization service
2. Stop the User Profile Service
3. Start the User Profile Service
4. Start the User Profile Synchronization service.

I hope the above should help you resolve the issues.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to start the Windows Service "User Profile Service". In addition I restarted IIS and the SharePoint Timer Service. After that the service application management page could be accessed. Good Luck!

Comment: I think this worked because you restarted IIS and the timer service. The User Profile Service Windows service is not related to SharePoint.